# Drop keyspace hangs

Tags: cassandra

Problem: `drop keyspace MyKeyspace;` hangs.

**Environment:** 
This is an Ubuntu 12.04 64bit in virtualbox, running a single Cassandra instance (on a development machine).

Cassandra is 1.1.6:

```
myuser@myhost:~$ /usr/bin/nodetool -h localhost version
ReleaseVersion: 1.1.6
```

Plenty of free disk space:

```
myuser@myhost:~$ df
Filesystem                1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/myhost-root   100232772 3100308  92112816   4% /
udev                        1016760       4   1016756   1% /dev
tmpfs                        410340     268    410072   1% /run
none                           5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
none                        1025844       0   1025844   0% /run/shm
/dev/sda1                    233191   24999    195751  12% /boot
```

Machine is idle:

```
myuser@myhost:~$ uptime
 21:24:50 up  3:46,  2 users,  load average: 0.06, 0.04, 0.05
```

**How I got there:**

The machine was running another db, all fine for long time. Now I created a new keyspace MyKeyspace, and run a Java program to import data (using titan graph, but that shouldn't matter). After a couple thousand of records imported (a couple of MB only) the import program did not make progress anymore, and logged 6 times:

```
418455 [RetryService : myhost(192.168.1.241):9160] INFO  com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.CountingConnectionPoolMonitor  - Reactivating myhost
```

Then my program (titan graph actually) gave up with:

```
com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.TemporaryStorageException: Temporary failure in storage backend
```

During all this time I was connected to `/usr/bin/cassandra-cli` and could successfully execute `show keyspaces;`.

Then I decided to start over; drop the keyspace. That's where it hangs now, for hours. It doesn't respond to ctrl-c either. Meanwhile I'm able to log in by ssh, connect with cassandra-cli, and run `show keyspaces;`. The keyspace is still there. Also, my Java app can access that data store, but it's read only. Reading succeeds, but writes fail. It's just a timeout I get from the titan graph library when writing:

```
com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanException: ID renewal thread on partition [2] did not complete in time. [60007 ms]
```

Any commands I could run to see what's going on? Should I report a bug?

Comment: Are there any exceptions in Cassandra's log?  Often the log is in /var/log/cassandra/system.log.

Answer (score 12):

If you have auto_snapshot enabled in cassandra.yaml (it's enabled by default), then Cassandra will take a snapshot before dropping the keyspace.  If you don't have JNA set up properly, this can sometimes cause problems, so I would check that first.

Comment: That worked for me. Only, there is a warning "If you set this flag to false, you will lose data on truncation or drop." from this page: https://forge.puppet.com/locp/cassandra — now I'm not too sure which data we're going to lose if we are to truncate a table... Do you have any such knowledge?

Comment: @AlexisWilke if you truncate a table with auto_snapshot disabled, the contents of that table will be lost unless you have another backup to restore from.