# Connection timed out while dropping keyspace

Tags: cassandra, cql

I'm having trouble deleting a keyspace.

The keyspace in question has 4 tables similar to this one:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE demo WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '1'}  AND durable_writes = false;

CREATE TABLE demo.t1 (
    t11 int,
    t12 timeuuid,
    t13 int,
    t14 text,
    t15 text,
    t16 boolean,
    t17 boolean,
    t18 int,
    t19 timeuuid,
    t110 text,
    PRIMARY KEY (t11, t12)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (t13 DESC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
CREATE INDEX t1_idx ON demo.t1 (t14);
CREATE INDEX t1_deleted_idx ON demo.t2 (t15);
```

When I want to delete the keyspace using the command:

```
    Session session = cluster.connect();
    PreparedStatement prepared = session.prepare("drop keyspace if exists " + schemaName);
    BoundStatement bound = prepared.bind();
    session.execute(bound);
```

Then the query gets timed out (or takes over 10 seconds to execute), even when the tables are empty:

> ```
> com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.OperationTimedOutException: [/192.168.0.1:9042] Timed out waiting for server response
>         at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.OperationTimedOutException.copy(OperationTimedOutException.java:44)
>         at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.OperationTimedOutException.copy(OperationTimedOutException.java:26)
>         at com.datastax.driver.core.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:37)
>         at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:245)
>         at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:64)
>         at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:39)
> ```

I tried this on multiple machines and the result was the same. I'm using Cassandra 3.9. A similar thing happens using cqlsh. I know that I can increase the read timeout in the cassandra.yaml file, but how can I make this dropping faster? Another thing is that if I do two consecutive requests, the first one gets timed out and the second one goes through fast.

Comment: Increasing timeout just hides the issue away and is usually a bad idea.

Have a look at this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/16618888/7413631

Answer (score 1):

Try to run it with increased timeout:

**cqlsh --request-timeout=3600** (in seconds, default 10 deconds)

There's should be also same setting on driver level. Review timeout session in this link:

http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.1/manual/socket_options/

Answer (score 0):

Increasing timeout just hides the issue away and is usually a bad idea. Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16618888/7413631